# Mobile navigation background-color

Tags: html, css, mobile, navigation, background-color

I'm a starting freelancer who's currently working on a website for an colleague. I'm a bit new to the responsive part of coding. I have coded a decent bit now and the website is almost done in my eyes but it needs some perfection.

My problem is when I put content under my navigation menu it somehow cancels out the background-color of my nav menu.
If there's someone who knows this type of errors and could help me fix it, I would be very happy!

Here's the code:

```css
.nav {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #25b24a;
  text-align: right;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav .Logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url(../img/logo2.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu a {
  clear: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #25b24a;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  clear: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #256FB8;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: .6s;
}

label {
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: none;
  width: 26px;
  float: right;
  color: #25b24a;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menu {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #25a24b;
    margin: 0;
    color: #25a24b;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .menu a:hover {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #25a24b;
    margin: 0;
    color: #256fb8;
  }
  .menu a.li {
    display: block;
  }
  #toggle:checked+.menu {
    display: block;
  }
}

#Home {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#Home .banner {
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc url(../img/headerfoto1.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container p.home-text {
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 480px;
}

#Home .container .button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  width: 135px;
  background: #256fb8;
  color: white;
  font-family: Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, " sans-serif";
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

#Home .container .button:hover {
  background: #25b24a;
  transition: .5s;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

#Home .container .button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}


/* Mobiel Home */

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-family: Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, " sans-serif";
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #256FB8;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
  }
  header {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 50px;
  }
  header nav {
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  header nav .Logo {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(../img/logo2.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -34px;
  }
  header nav a.hamburger {
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  header nav ul {
    width: 450px;
    height: auto;
  }
  header nav ul li {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: none;
  }
  #Home .banner {
    padding-top: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ccc url(../img/headerfoto1.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .container {
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .container p.home-text {
    padding: 0px 4px 4px 15px;
    width: 320px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="Logo">
    <!-- Logo in css -->
  </div>
  <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
  <div class="menu">
    <a class="li" href="#Home"> Home </a>
    <a class="li" href="#Diensten"> Diensten </a>
    <a class="li" href="#Werkwijze"> Werkwijze </a>
    <a class="li" href="#Over-mij"> Over Mij </a>
    <a class="li" href="#Contact"> Contact </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Home">
  <div class="banner">
    <!-- banner afbeelding in css -->

  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h1> Mobile navigation, background-color </h1>
    <p class="home-text">
      I want the mobile navigation menu to have a white solid background. The problem is; once I put more content into the html it somehow cancels out the background-color in the navigation menu. I hope someone could help me. Thanks!
    </p>

    <div class="button"> <a href="#Diensten"> button </a> </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Cannot reproduce it here- https://jsfiddle.net/h8ujszfm/ .. Can you reproduce the issue in the fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content is placed after the menu, therefore is shown above the main element.

You need to add a higher z-index so it's shown above. For z-index to take effect, you also need to specify any position different than the default one(static.
Add this to the nav element

```
.nav {
 position:relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Haha thats it!
Thought it had something to do with z-index but didnt put it in the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is supposed to look like:
https://codepen.io/jessekoops10/pen/VMBPdY

```
/* HTML */

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
<body>

  <div class="nav">
                <div class="Logo"> <!-- Logo in css --> </div>
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
        <div class="menu">
            <a class="li" href="#Home"> Home </a>
            <a class="li" href="#Diensten"> Diensten </a>
            <a class="li" href="#Werkwijze"> Werkwijze </a>
            <a class="li" href="#Over-mij"> Over Mij </a>
            <a class="li" href="#Contact"> Contact </a>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>


/* CSS */

.nav {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #25b24a;
    text-align: right;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav .Logo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(../img/logo2.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}


.menu {
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu a {
    clear: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #25b24a;
    margin: 0 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.menu a:hover {
    clear: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #256FB8;
    margin: 0 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: .6s;
}

label {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: none;
    width: 26px;
    float: right;
    color: #25b24a;
}
#toggle {
    display: none;
}


    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        label {
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .menu {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            display: none;
        }

        .menu a {
            display: block;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #25a24b;
            margin: 0;
            color: #25a24b;
            background-color: aqua;
        }

        .menu a:hover {
            display: block;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #25a24b;
            margin: 0;
            color: #256fb8;
        }

        .menu a.li {
            display: block;
        }


        #toggle:checked + .menu {
            display: block;
        }

    }
```